# How to add an object in my collection by only using add method?

Tags: java, object, collections

I have to create a collection of Name,Address,Age.How do I create this as a collection object in java.

My snippet is as follows:

```
public class DataCollection implements java.io.Serializable{

    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private int Age;
}
```

And I have the getter and setter methods...

In the main method, how do I create this as a collection??

```
list.add(new DataCollection(??????) );
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Off topic. In the future you should start classes with an uppercase letter (e.g. `DataCollection`)

Comment: and your member names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DataCollection implements java.io.Serializable{

    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private int Age;
    public DataCollection(String name, String address, int age){
            this.Name=name;
            this.Address=address;
            this.Age=age;
    }
}
```

After that create `DataCollection` objects:

```
DataCollection d1 = new DataCollection("nik", "10/5 cross", 20);//creation of List collection
```

Now put the object inside a collection:

```
List<DataCollection> list = new LinkedList<DataCollection>();
list.add(d1);
```

You can iterate like below:

```
List<DataCollection> list=new LinkedList<DataCollection>();
for(DataCollection d : list){
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: When I try to use LinkedList it gives me error like LinkedList is not generic.It cannot be parameterizec with arguments<DataCollection>.

Comment: @user2988935 You have to import this two: `import java.util.LinkedList;`
`import java.util.List;`. Make sure you use this `LinkedList` rather than some arbitrary implementation.

Comment: @Trying... Thanks a lot. Is there a way to check the objects in the collection? I am using the list.get(i) but it returns the index. Is there anyway I can get the value ?

Comment: @user2988935 see the edit in the answer.

Comment: Yes I tried. But I get the arbitrary values like ecd55fca,fa79750e,57b9a57,c83bc96b.... whereas the actual values are different. Kindly help.

Comment: You are printing a pointer to the object. try `System.out.println(d.getName())` or override the `toString()` method

Comment: @user2988935 override toString() method in the class `DataCollection `.

Comment: I am sorry... one more question. How can I add these of objects in Map.. If i give map.update(key,list) will it work?

Comment: When I try to do it, it shows me ClassNotFoundException. My classpath is all set with correct jars but still the error is shown...

Comment: This is after adding the Map...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question exactly what you are asking. I suspect the problem is that you are trying to allocate a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is an abstract class. You should be allocating a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), or something of that sort. For a minimal example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DataCollection implements java.io.Serializable{

    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private int Age;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<DataCollection> list = new ArrayList<DataCollection>();
        list.add(new DataCollection());
    }   
}
```

Then you can use `list.get(index)` to access the item in the list and set a name. The other problem may be that you want to pass arguments in when you create the object (such as the name, address, and age. If that is what you want to do, you need to look up [overloading constructors](http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/oop/oop-45-constructor-overloading.html).

Comment: @Shreyos,@blubob.. based on your answers, I have updated my code as shown below: Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No.  You instantiate a List with an ArrayList or LinkedList.  List<DataCollection> list = new ArrayList<DataCollection>();  You instantiate to an interface when you can.  You instantiate to a concrete class when there is no interface or you need to use a method in the concrete class.

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

  public final String getName() 
  public final String getAddress() 
  public final int Age() 
  public final void setName(String aName)
  public final void setAddress(String aAddress)
  public final void setAge(int aAge)
Main Mthod:  
List<DataCollection> list = new ArrayList<DataCollection>();
DataCollection dataCollection = new DataCollection();
dataCollection .setName("John");
dataCollection .setAddress("Chicago");
dataCollection .setAge(21);
list.adddataCollection();