# How do I create a new instance of a collection

Tags: java

I am trying to create an empty collection but apparently collections.emptySet() is apparently not the way?
Google tells me to create a new instance instead...
How do I create a new instance of a collection?

Comment: start here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: There are many types of collections (`List`, `Set`, `Map`) and different implementations for each of them. Use the constructor from the one you need.

Comment: Why you don't like `Collections.emptySet()`? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Becase I want to fill my collection at a later time and apparently you cant if you use Collections.emptySet()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create collection objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961062/how-to-create-collection-objects)

Comment: Great, the new Hashset<>() works great

Answer (score 6):

`Collections#emptyXyz`, in this case [`Collections#emptySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet--), returns an **immutable** empty collection for the determined interface. If you want/need to initialize your collection, just do it like this:

```
Set<YourClass> set = new HashSet<>(); //or choose another implementation
```

In this case, the `set` will be initialized and empty and later you can add data into it. If this variable is a field in your class, then initialize it in the constructor rather than as a local variable:

```
public class Foo {
    Set<YourClass> set;
    public Foo() {
        set = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

In the future, please refer to the documentation first.

Comment: don't encourage this questions with answers.... :(

Comment: @JordiCastilla if you read the question, OP's mainly asking why `Collections#emptySet` won't work as expected. And IMHO the names of those methods are confusing, by the way :), I think they should be `Collections#emptyImmutableXyz`.

Comment: *I am trying to create an empty collection but apparently collections.emptySet() is apparently not the way?* this means OP didn't take any effort of reading about `Collections` either `Java` basic object management.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I know, and sadly there's lot of people that won't and comments won't make them do that either. So, you can choose to help OP with a proper answer or just downvote, comment and leave. I don't worry about earning/losing rep with this post, just solving OP's issue.

Comment: solve OP's issue is to guide through a tutorial to start with the basis... code you posted will solve OP's concrete question? **YES** but I bet OP's wont understand what he is doing. PS: i either worry about losing rep's with this question, **I'm worried about SO quality**.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I'm worried too, but I don't see you contributing either. And that's not a dup q/a, read it well. If you feel this is a bad q/a, create a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) about it.

Comment: Of course you won't see me contributing with OP here, I'm doing it by giving you my opinion... And... think about why a question has 5 downvotes and if it's me or you who must create a meta post to defend position

Comment: @JordiCastilla whatever, I'm not arguing here in comments w/you anymore.

Comment: do it here then: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290875/should-this-question-be-flagged-or-answered

Comment: @JordiCastilla - Since you raise this issue on meta, I am curious: Did you downvote this answer?

Comment: @TravisJ , yes, I downvoted bcause I wasn't agree with answering this question. After raised the question to meta, reading answers and dupes make me better understanding the situation I removed it. That was the point to post on meta: as I wrote, I wasn't agree with answeing, but as long as Luiggi has much more experience than me probably I was wrong, which is exactly what happened... My conclusion: *it's not worthy to punish good answers, or answers at all to bad questions*...